# Why <style type="text/css"> works and why <style type="css"> does not work here?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <style type="text/css" >
          body { background-color:#003;} 
       </style>   
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code changes body color to blue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style type="css" >
      body { background-color:#003;} 
   </style>   
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I repeat the same with `<style type = "css">` the body color doesn't changes. Why?

Comment: Probably because `<style type="text/css">` is the right way of defining a `style` tag. *The value "text/css" indicates that the content is CSS.*. See documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_type.asp.

Answer (score 2):

`text/css` is [the registered MIME type for CSS](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/css).

`css` is not a valid MIME type at all.

Since the browser doesn't recognise the MIME type `css`, it doesn't know which stylesheet engine it should use, so it ignores the stylesheet entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Because `css` isn't a valid type.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style:

> This attribute defines the styling language as a MIME type (charset
>   should not 
>       be specified). This attribute is optional and defaults to text/css if it is not 
>       specified — there is very little reason to include this in modern web 
>       documents.